# Hibernate (suspend to disk) not opening back apps

Tags: suspend, hibernate, 23.10

When I use `sudo systemctl hibernate` to put my system into a hibernation state instead of just shutting it down and then when I open it back up, none of my applications are opening back up. Every time at start-up (just normal start-up) I usually get some errors/warnings at the starting (which is the case for many people) but during the first start-up after hibernation, additional logs appear on the screen which basically say that the data of the opened applications which was previously written onto the hard drive is being cleared (according to my understanding since I can't actually get the log that was displayed on the screen). Can anyone help me fix it?

Edit: As far as I remember, the message on start-up said "clearing orphaned node"

Comment: First step is to put a pin in the timestream with
```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
``` Then, do your suspend thing. When your system is usable again,
```
sudo journalctl --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
``` This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.

Comment: @waltinator is the most recent one on the top or on the bottom? I just remembered some of the log showed up on the screen during startuip which said "clearing orphaned node"